# How properly turn off (write code without) null safety in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to properly downgrade flutter version without null safety? The important project was written without it and now I don't want to use null safety. How can I do these properly?

Now my sdk version is:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

I want to downgrade to environment:

sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: What happened when you did?

Comment: Documentation on using unsound null safety was literally the first result on google for `flutter disable null safety`: https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety Looks like exactly what you want.